# Apache's virtual host won't work using MAMP because of Pow.cx

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

I've been struggling with this problem for a while and don't know why I can't acces my virtual host, these are the steps I took:

1. **httpd.conf:**

`# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

2. **/etc/host:**

`'127.0.0.1 mysite-dev.com'`.

3. **http-vhosts.conf:**

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Volumes/Miguel/Documents/Workspace/htdocs
    ServerName mysite-dev.com
</VirtualHost>`

4. Restart MAMP
5. Access the url through Chrome, the site isn't loaded and I get the error 'connection refused'

Comment: What URL are you using to access your local site?

Comment: i'm using http://mysite-dev.com, which is the url I define in /etc/hosts

Comment: Try accessing it using 127.0.0.1/mysite-dev.com. For whatever reason, I have not been able to access my localhost sites using the names I gave them in the hosts file.; but I can connect to them using the 127.0.0.1 IP.

Comment: thank you for your help... finally I found out what was going own. I'm using Pow.cx to ceate 'virtual hosts' for Ruby on Rails applications. it was taking control over port 80 so it was impossible to do the connection with my Apache host.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Pow.cx is taking control over port 80 and that's the reason why I can't access my virtual Host... guess I'll try ton config Pow in a way I can use both without any problem.

If anyone else has this same problem you can follow through this guide:

http://nikhgupta.com/code/serving-legacy-php-applications-using-apache-alongside-pow/